# Three question on Permutation and combination

Tags: combinatorics

1.**How many  number of three digit even numbers than can be formed out of the digits 0 to 9 ?**

The question seems confusing since there is no mention of whether repetition is allowed or not ?! since if repetition is allowed then the answer would be **450** (`5*9*10`) where as if not then the answer would be **328** (`9p2+ 4*(8*8) = 328`).

Am I correct about the question or am missing some point ?

**2.How many calendars that can be prepared for the month of February ?**

**3.A golf player wants to put the ball in the hole in 5 shots. He says that he will put the ball in the hole at most by 3 shots and will qualify for the next round. how many number of possibilities of shots he had played ?**

I don't have any clue for this two.

Comment: Not meaning to be harsh, but, without additional context, the first question is ambiguous and the last two questions are incoherent.  I suspect that the intended interpretation to these questions would become clearer by looking at solutions to related examples provided by the same source.

Answer (score 2):

1. I get the same answers you do.  I also agree the question is unclear on repetition.
2. Think of how many ways the pattern of days in February can be different, starting day of week and length
3. I don't understand this question

Comment: In addition, only 10-digit numbers can be formed from the digits 0 to 9.  So the answer could also be zero.